# Calling the same page with PHP form without losing header & footer

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a simple form with PHP, `home.php`, the form submits to itself;

```
<form action="home.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddImageForm">
```

But `home.php` is called from the `index.php` file (below) so when I submit the form and it calls the same page it's missing the header and footer.

```
<?php
  include("includes/header.php");

  if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'gallery') {
      include("gallery.php");

  } else {
      include("home.php");

  }
  include("includes/footer.php");

?>
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting it to index.php?

```
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddImageForm">
```

Or maybe a full path to index.php is what you want

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddImageForm">
```

Comment: I'm building this in xampp and using your suggestion it takes me to `http://localhost/dashboard/`

Comment: @bonEte change action to the actual location of `index.php`

Comment: @IdontDownVote Thanks. I should of thought about it before rushing to add a `/` That worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes Submitting it to racine,  action without value.

`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddImageForm">`

And make the job into home.php (Verify !empty($_POST) inside)